# IBM liberty datasource taking too much time (after AWS RDS failover)

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-rds, websphere-liberty, failover

I have configured the datasource with oracle connection details like below.

```
<dataSource id="auditLogDatasource" jndiName="jdbc/audit_log" type="javax.sql.DataSource" validationTimeout="10s">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>

        <properties.oracle description="main db pipe" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin://@localhost:1686/mkapp"
                           password="test" user="test"/>
        <connectionManager id="ConnectionManager"
                           maxPoolSize="30" minPoolSize="1" purgePolicy="FailingConnectionOnly" />
</dataSource>
```

Java code

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/audit_log")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    if (this.dataSource == null) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}

public void store(@Observes AuditRecord auditRecord) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        log.info("DB connection requested");
        con = this.dataSource.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
        int index = 1;
        preparedStatement.setString(index++, auditRecord.getAction());
        preparedStatement.setString(index++, auditRecord.getUserInitiating());
        preparedStatement.setString(index++, auditRecord.getUserAffected());
        preparedStatement.setString(index++, auditRecord.getAdditionalInfo());
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(index++, new Timestamp(auditRecord.getCreateTime().getTime()));
        preparedStatement.setString(index++, auditRecord.getServer());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        log.info("DB record added");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially everything working fine mostly I am seeing only 1 Free connection count.

> But once I trigger AWS RDS failover (Reboot with failover) server
>   taking too much time to discard the invalid connection from pool & creating new connection.

```
2019/11/15 17:31:28.571 [Default Executor-thread-60] INFO dao.AuditDao : DB connection requested
2019/11/15 17:47:03.741 [Default Executor-thread-60] INFO dao.AuditDao : DB record added
```

**error in message.log after 16 min**

```
[ERROR   ] J2CA0081E: Method destroy failed while trying to execute method destroy on ManagedConnection WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@10e0477e from resource No longer available. Caught exception: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.exceptions.DataStoreAdapterException: DSRA0080E: An exception was received by the Data Store Adapter. See original exception message: {0}. with SQL State : 08000 SQL Code : 17410
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.destroy(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.test.auth.dao.AuditDao.store(AuditDao.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.test.auth.AuthHomeServlet.audit(AuthHomeServlet.java:72)
    at com.test.auth.AuthHomeServlet.doPost(AuthHomeServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.test.auth.UserPrincipalFilter.doFilter(MkidUserPrincipalFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08000, Error Code = 17,410
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:350)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:61)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:574)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:4011)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.destroy(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2508)
    ... 17 more
```

Is there any way that I can configure the connection close timeout ? though I configured the validationTimeout seems like it is not working.

```
Liberty version: 17.0.0.4
Database product version : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
JDBC driver version  : 12.1.0.2.0
Driver lib: ojdbc6.jar / ojdbc7.jar
```

Is it related to DNS issue? Can anyone point me to right direction...

**UPDATE**

This is what I got from thread dump

```
Default Executor-thread-29" #87 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa06793d800 nid=0x13d03 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700012743000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.isProxySession(PhysicalConnection.java:4398)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000007bd6d0900> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.OracleHelper.doConnectionCleanup(OracleHelper.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.cleanupStates(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2847)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.cleanup(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2774)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.cleanup(MCWrapper.java:1541)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.cleanupAndDestroyMCWrapper(FreePool.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:1602)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:581)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:112)
    at test.dao.AuditDao.store(AuditDao.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:92)
    at test.AuthHomeServlet.audit(AuthHomeServlet.java:72)
    at test.AuthHomeServlet.doPost(AuthHomeServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:729)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at test.MkidUserPrincipalFilter.doFilter(MkidUserPrincipalFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1001)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1139)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1010)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:938)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1136)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:482)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:347)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1077)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1803)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:503)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:573)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007822c8b38> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

**From requestTiming feature**

```
[11/17/19 20:03:22:442 AEDT] 000000ee com.ibm.ws.request.timing.manager.SlowRequestManager         W TRAS0112W: Request AAAcI1bXZti_AAAAAAAAAAD has been running on thread 000000df for at least 30016.328ms. The following stack trace shows what this thread is currently running.

     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.OracleHelper.doConnectionCleanup(OracleHelper.java:355)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.cleanupStates(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2752)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.cleanup(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2679)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.cleanup(MCWrapper.java:1492)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.cleanupAndDestroyMCWrapper(FreePool.java:444)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:1543)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:547)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:283)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:143)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:116)
     at com.testt.auth.dao.AuditDao.store(AuditDao.java:37)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
     at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
     at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
     at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
     at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
     at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:91)
     at com.test.auth.AuthHomeServlet.audit(AuthHomeServlet.java:72)
     at com.test.auth.AuthHomeServlet.doPost(AuthHomeServlet.java:37)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:147)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
     at com.test.auth.MkidUserPrincipalFilter.doFilter(MkidUserPrincipalFilter.java:38)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:995)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1004)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:76)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:957)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:357)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:316)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:499)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:433)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:313)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
     at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1029)
     at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:695)
     at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:383)
     at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:947)
     at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:85)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)

The following table shows the events that have run during this request.

Duration      Operation
30018.682ms + websphere.servlet.service | auth | authHomeServlet
```

Comment: Change the `purgePolicy="FailingConnectionOnly"` to `purgePolicy="EntirePool"` and make test to see if it will be better. It should, as it should discard whole pool after switch and failing first connection.

Comment: @Gas but it is taking time to fail the existing connection which affects the user which it is serving, this is where I am trying to concentrate.

Comment: Such case may suggest that you have some firewall in between, which doesnt close connection properly when the db is gone, so check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to Oracle UCP, this issue disappeared as it has timeout on connection validation (15 sec). I posted this issue on [Openliberty github](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/10137), hope it will be fixed in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Although the error which is ultimately reported is on Connection.close, that does not necessarily mean that the close operation is what is taking all of the time.  Several [thread dumps](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_dump_server.html) captured during the interval could help show where the delay is, if you are able to collect that.  You will also want to consider the validationTimeout, which you have configured to 10 seconds. `validationTimeout="10s"`.  This value doesn't impact the close operation, but instead determines the timeout value that is supplied to the [Connection.isValid(timeout)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid-int-) operation, which is used to check the validity of the connection.  By specifying the 10 second value, you are giving the JDBC driver up to 10 seconds to determine if the connection is still valid.  You might be able to lessen the delay by reducing this value or eliminating from the configuration altogether.

Comment: after seeing requestTiming feature logs i can say like connection cleanup only taking much time. If I cancel the web request & try another one then new connection not taking any time. But pool monitoring stats showing that one connection is in hold (busy on cleaning). Looks like close method trying to reach the server which is not available. Don't know where to configure this timeout.

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional stack.  Here is the source for the code around OracleHelper.java:355, https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/934b25508be3454354e54fff30165642e6a7cfbc/dev/com.ibm.ws.jdbc/src/com/ibm/ws/rsadapter/impl/OracleHelper.java#L350
which is reflective invocation of code like this:
```
if (((OracleConnection) con).isProxySession())
  ((OracleConnection) con).close(OracleConnection.PROXY_SESSION);
```
You'll need to take this up with Oracle support why the proxy session close takes so long.